# grep / sed / awk / count between two lines in file not whole file

Tags: command-line, bash, python, grep, sed

I have this file on my laptop `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">

<!--
  This file is part of systemd.

  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
  (at your option) any later version.
-->

<busconfig>

        <policy user="root">
                <allow own="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
                <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
        </policy>

        <policy context="default">
                <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
                <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
        </policy>

</busconfig>
```

I need to know if:

```
<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
```

exists but only if it's **not under** `root` and **must be under** `default`.

Searching the file **must** only be between:

```
    <policy context="default">
```

and the next line that contains:

```
    </policy>
```

I'm looking for the most elegant (and readable) way of doing this without any bias towards `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or any other common utility.

This is part of a python program displaying a expandable/collapsible tkinter treeview of DBus. I am trapping out permission errors on system bus that can't be introspected. Introspect and deny are already successfully trapping but trapping too much. Because it is python the `json` and `xmltree` modules are already being used and python built-in `list` and `dict` functions are available.

Comment: Not elegant, but might work for you:  `sed -n '/<policy context="default">/,/<\/policy>/p' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf | grep '<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"\/>' || echo "Not Found"`

Comment: @Terrance Thanks. I'll give that a shot tomorrow and let you know. FYI `allow own` was yesterday's mission which worked great. Today's mission is `allow send_destination` which is causing problems.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that and corrected my mistake.  =)

Comment: @Terrance Uncanny coincidence though :)

Comment: You have started down the "Parse XML by hand" path. It is a long, winding, confusing path. Are sure you wish to proceed?

Comment: @waltinator Just a little XML in python to date. But I did parse HTML from Ask Ubuntu Q&A SQL Database in Bash, and JSON from gmail.com metadadta in Bash and that was "complicated". Learning python has been a breath of fresh air and I look forward to rewriting all that bash stuff in python.

Comment: Suggesting python is helping. Please also suggest a parser library (minidom, BeautifulSoup, ...)

Comment: @Terrance It works perfectly. If you want to post an answer I'll certainly upvote it. I still need to try out other answer(s) before accepting one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install `xmllint`:

> ```
> apt-get install libxml2-utils
> ```

Check wether your xml path exists in context `default`:

> ```
> xmllint --xpath "//busconfig/policy[@context='default']/allow[@send_destination='org.freedesktop.thermald']" /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo good || echo bad
> ```

Check vice-versa if your path is inexistent in the other context:

> ```
> ! xmllint --xpath "//busconfig/policy[@user='root']/allow[@send_destination='org.freedesktop.thermald']" /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo good || echo bad
> ```

Comment: I did a little digging and it appears `xmllint` is an excellent command line utility. My program already requires lots of extra Python libraries be installed and I'm not sure I want to burden users with another. Also I already use this in two places: `import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET` which can do what `xmllint` can do, only I didn't realize it until now. Most of my Python program is copy and pasted from Stack Overflow dozens upon dozens of Q&As.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, `grep` and `awk` (but not all together):

```
sed -n '/<policy context="default">/,/<\/policy>/p' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf | grep '<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"\/>' || echo "Not Found"
```

or

```
awk '/<policy context="default">/,/<\/policy>/' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf | grep '<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"\/>' || echo "Not Found"
```

---

Examples:

Searching for `allow send_destination`:

```
$ sed -n '/<policy context="default">/,/<\/policy>/p' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf | grep '<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"\/>' || echo "Not Found"
Not Found
```

Searching for `deny send_destination`:

```
$ sed -n '/<policy context="default">/,/<\/policy>/p' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf | grep '<deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"\/>' || echo "Not Found"
                <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
```

`awk` works pretty much the same as `sed`:

```
$ awk '/<policy context="default">/,/<\/policy>/' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf | grep '<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"\/>' || echo "Not Found"
Not Found
```

and

```
$ awk '/<policy context="default">/,/<\/policy>/' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.thermald.conf | grep '<deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"\/>' || echo "Not Found"
                <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.thermald"/>
```